# How do you change the installation order in Dell Inspiron 3580

Tags: dell, laptop, inspiron

I booted Ubuntu installation from USB bootable falsh drive. After it completed installation and restarting, the computer does not find bootable device. How do I change the installation order in Dell Inspiron 3580 laptop to point to the hard-drive where ubuntu is installed.

Comment: I entered BIOS using F2. However, I don't see a boot option for my hard drive. Does that mean Ubuntu did not install correctly?

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to press **F12** as you start up the laptop for entering the **Boot Menu** and select the appropriate entry. Note that you may need to spam the key to get the timing right.

If you wish to make permanent changes to the boot order, on startup press **F2** for BIOS settings and navigate the menu to make the appropriate changes.

However, if there's no bootable device listed in either menu, your installation process didn't install a proper boot flag or didn't overwrite windows's MBR, in which case your question needs more details to be answered.